# Can I put Google Analytics code in the html files of my Android webview app?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have an Android app that uses a WebView to load html pages. Instead of putting the code in the Java part of the app, can I just put it on the html pages of the app. Will it still work like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logging into google analytics requires a context variable, so I think it's not possible.

Comment: I tried it, it ended up not working, but I figured out to use analytics in the app. That was my problem, I was having trouble getting the analytics code to work in the app, so I was trying to find an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: @peedeefish call you tell me more about the way you fixed..i have encountered a similar issue. Thanks